# Is there a program to read the content of the Mac OS X Drag Clipbaord?

Tags: objective-c, macos, drag-and-drop, clipboard

Is there a way / a script / a program / some kind of binary for Mac OS X to read the content of the so called "Drag Clipboard"?

This is needed if you want to know which files or folders the user dragged around lately (e.g. on the Desktop, in a folder, on a dock icon, etc...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I haven't found anything which fits my needs I wrote a tiny Objective-C script and put it on github: https://github.com/tofi86/readDragboard

A compiled binary (built with Xcode 5.1, SDK 10.9 for OS X 10.6 and newer) is available at https://github.com/tofi86/readDragboard/releases